# Plot marker above candle when True - Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

**Question**

How do I plot a marker (arrow, dot or similar) above a candle when `df["Close Above Open"]` is `True`

**Current chart**

[image: current chart]

**Desired output**

[image: desired output]

**Reproducible example code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def genMockDataFrame(days,startPrice,colName,startDate,seed=None): 
   
    periods = days*24
    np.random.seed(seed)
    steps = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.0018, size=periods)
    steps[0]=0
    P = startPrice+np.cumsum(steps)
    P = [round(i,4) for i in P]

    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'ticker':np.repeat( [colName], periods ),
        'date':np.tile( pd.date_range(startDate, periods=periods, freq='H'), 1 ),
        'price':(P)})
    fxDF.index = pd.to_datetime(fxDF.date)
    fxDF = fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()
    fxDF.columns = [i.title() for i in fxDF.columns]
    return fxDF


df = genMockDataFrame(15,1.1904,'eurusd','19/3/2020',seed=157)

df["Close Above Open"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Close >= x.Open,axis=1)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.index,

                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close'])])



fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def genMockDataFrame(days,startPrice,colName,startDate,seed=None): 

    periods = days*24
    np.random.seed(seed)
    steps = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.0018, size=periods)
    steps[0]=0
    P = startPrice+np.cumsum(steps)
    P = [round(i,4) for i in P]

    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'ticker':np.repeat( [colName], periods ),
        'date':np.tile( pd.date_range(startDate, periods=periods, freq='H'), 1 ),
        'price':(P)})
    fxDF.index = pd.to_datetime(fxDF.date)
    fxDF = fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()
    fxDF.columns = [i.title() for i in fxDF.columns]
    return fxDF


df = genMockDataFrame(15,1.1904,'eurusd','19/3/2020',seed=157)

df["Close Above Open"] = df["High"].where(df["Close"] >= df["Open"])

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.index,

                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close'], )])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=(1 + .003)*df["Close Above Open"], 
mode='markers', marker=dict(color='Blue', size=12)))
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False, showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```